# angular.js non-GET instance action returns error: value.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

```
    var user = $resource('/user/:action',{},{
        create: {method:'POST',isArray:true, params:{action:'save'}},
    });
    user.$create(function(userData) {
    //do something          
    });
```

The HTTP result code is 200, and proper data is returned for the $create.
The 'on success' function call fails with the error below:

```
Error: value.push is not a function
  resourceFactory/</Resource[name]/promise</<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular-resource.js:532
```

etc.

The returned JSON from $create IS an array.
If I remove the function call from $create(..) and make it $create() - it works fine.

I guess(?) that this has to do with Array vs. Object, but as I said - I know the result IS an array JSON, and (well) I tried both permutations..

Edit:
I think that Angular has a problem with how the response format. (?)
It's an array with (sometimes) one element. Is this format incorrect?

```
[{
     "hashcode": "0",
     "object-type": "aa",
}]
```

Thanks

Comment: Where do you use the variable "value"?

Comment: nowhere. I think it's something in Angular

Comment: Is user0 a typo? Btw. funny how you asked a question about value.push, yet you never show it in your code.

Comment: @Shomz Yes it's a typo, and yes it's funny - but it comes from Angular code not mine :-)

Comment: Oh I see, very interesting indeed!

Comment: this is a class-action, not an instance-action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and it seems that $resource object, when it makes a post request can't accept an array in response or that may be a bug. Anyways, I was able to work this around by converting the array response from the server to a json response. so in your case a server response, something like this should work -->

```
{ "response" : [{
     "hashcode": "0",
     "object-type": "aa",
}]}
```

Comment: You're right. I had to re-implement this on the server side, just for Angular. That's annoying.  Thanks.

Comment: @JRun I actually used the `transformResponse` field to wrap the array in an object and didn't have to change anything on the server

Answer (score 8):

I came across the same issue, when using the instance-post-approach:

```
// Resource definition
var MyResource = $resource('/api/myresource/:id', 
  { id: '@id' },
  { save: {method: 'POST', isArray: true} }
);
// ...
var myInstance = new MyResource();
myInstance.$save(attributes).then(...);  // Expects result to be object
```

However, using the non-instance-based method, the result of the post is returned properly in an array:

```
// Resource definition as above ...
MyResource.save(attributes).$promise.then(...);  // Expects result to be array
```

Comment: This worked for me. When using $save with the resource instance I always had a "push" is not a function as if it didn't understand the array from the http response.

Comment: Using the non-instance based method also worked for me.

Comment: so is this behaviour a bug or intended by design?

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing [the API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource): the only required parameter for non-GET class actions is the `postData` object. From the docs:

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be
>   invoked with the following parameters:
>
> […]
>
> - non-GET "class" actions: `Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])`

… but you're only passing a callback:

```
user.$create(function(userData) {
    //do something          
});
```

Pass a data object as the first argument, and it should be fine:

```
user.$create( {} , function(userData) {
    //do something
});
```